# Is it possible to know how many applications are registered to a particular module of the phone

Tags: android, android-manifest

I was wondering if there is any specific way to know how many Apps are registered to particular module of the device. For example... HTC and Samsung phone comes with customized **music players** for their own devices, but user may have installed other music players like winamp. In this case, is there some api or any other way to check how many apps has registered as **music player** for the device?

Any help or leads is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
SKU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept in Android of a music player any more than there is a concept in Android of a dental procedure guidebook.

What you *can* do is use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to see what all might respond to a given Intent.

For example, some things that you would consider a "music player" might have an activity that responds to `ACTION_VIEW` for a MIME type of `audio/mp3` or `audio/mpeg`. Via `PackageManager`, you can find those activities. However, there will be other "music players" that do not offer such an activity, since they don't play arbitrary files, but rather their own content (e.g., Spotify) or streams (e.g., TuneIn Radio).